# setTimeout ajax throttle not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, timer

I have a timer, and a function that retrieves data everytime the user clicks certain buttons.  To avoid rapid succession of retrieving data

So I have a timer

```
  var timer;
```

Then a function to update something via ajax

```
  function doTheThing(data){
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $.ajax({
        url:'/post/url',
        data:data,
    }).done(function(data){
       timer = setTimeout(function(){
           getMoreData();
       },2000);
    });
   }
```

Theoretically this should start the timer on every request, but if the user successively hits buttons to cause multiple requests, it will clear the last, and start fresh.  Inside the timer, I have the getMoreData(), to hopefully only retrieve once, if the user presses buttons 2 or more times successively.

```
   function getMoreData(){
       ...another ajax request, which I only really want to fire once,
       ... if the user presses buttons very fast to trigger that first one
   }
```

However, this isn't working.  I am getting just as many requests to getMoreData(), as I am button presses.

So my timer isn't working.  Whats the deal??

Comment: I used to think `$.ajax` would return a promise no?

Comment: The term for this is "debounce". There are many, many libraries out there which can help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is not working is because you're clearing the timeout in `doTheThing(data)`. There's a delay for every ajax request. So if you click rapidly, the `clearTimeout` will be called before any `setTimeout` is registered and basically does nothing.

Consider moving it to your `getMoreData` method, [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/96ybygvp/)

```
function getMoreData(){
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer = setTimeout(...)
   //Your other ajax   
}
```